# When i press F5, an "Attach to Process" window opens

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, attach-to-process

I have so many different C# source projects that run OK on other computers.

But on one computer, using Visual Studio 2013, when i press F5 to run the project, the "Attach to Process" window opens.

I searched a lot but no one have had my problem.
Why is it like this? How can i fix it?

---

**Edit:**

I re installed the VS with C# configurations but it did not change anything. the Start Debugging option is disabled just like the screen shot below:
[image]

Comment: is the issue that Attach to Process pops up, or that it doesn't just start debugging?

Comment: both, i want to start debugging but the windows pops up instead.

Comment: Well thats interesting... And you definitely have a startup project set?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET yes... I have it set.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398767/f5-or-start-debugging-button-is-greyed-out-for-winform-application ? Made sure there wasn't *multiple* startup projects set: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cb10e83a-70b6-43b4-9527-dc5ce9115dcf/visual-studio-2010-start-debugging-button-is-greyed-out?forum=vsdebug

Comment: @BradleyDotNET the problem was solved using the accepted answer of the post you mentioned. Write it in the answers to receive your reputation.

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee Done. Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will occur when you don't have a startup project set.

Right click the project you want to start and select "Set as Startup Project". Now F5 will run that project.

One other thing to try; from [F5 or Start Debugging Button is Greyed Out for Winform application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398767/f5-or-start-debugging-button-is-greyed-out-for-winform-application) is to:

1. Exclude the project from you application
2. Build the solution
3. Re-add the project
4. Build again
5. Set the project as the startup project

Comment: All of my solutions have startup project. I also tried to open csproj files. So this is not the case i think.

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee You could also check that VS wasn't installed with the wrong dev setup. Have you checked the hotkey list?

Comment: I re installed the VS with the C# dev setup. I also added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have DebugDiag or some other debugger (e.g. WinDbg) running in the background? Sometimes they are configured to automatically attach to a running process. Keep in mind only one debugger can be attached to one process.