# Visual Studio doesn't run programs

Tags: visual-studio

I downloaded visual studio for C# and now my problem is that when I run a program the very first time it runs without issues but the second time after exiting the program it shows this (pressing f5 also does nothing):

[image: pressing f5 also does nothing]

I have tried repairing Visual Studio and uninstalling and reinstalling it but that also doesn't work. It happens to other files too like Python files or asp.net files. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Is the issue only with one specific program or with every program you run?  Have you tried creating a new program to see if the issue happens there?

Answer (score -1):

Try setting your project as a `StartUp Project`.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398767/f5-or-start-debugging-button-is-greyed-out-for-winform-application) for details.

Comment: I assume this did not help?

Comment: No no It did help actually but it took some time but visual studio run perfectly thank you very much.