# Why my Start Debugging option F5 is disabled in Visual studio 2022?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to create a cloud script for my game. For that I have to use Azure functions and was following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio) and just installed visual studio 2022 .In the documentation under "Run the function locally" , to run the function I have to press the F5 button. But when I press the nothing happens.After exploring a bit I found that under "Debug" ,"Start Debugging F5" is greyed outScreenShot of Stop Debugging Greyed Out

I searched online and as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398767/f5-or-start-debugging-button-is-greyed-out-for-winform-application) you have to selected "set as startup project". But no such option exists.The other solution doesn't make sense to me.
[image: Screen Shot of the problem]
Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: I'd guess you used File > New > File instead of File > New > Project.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio#create-a-function-app-project

Comment: @HansPassant No I didnt do that. Infact I redid the process again. What I can understand is as per the documentation under "Rename the function", as per Step 1 when you In File Explorer rename the file, it is then creating the problem, because before renaming the file the debug option is present

Comment: That's a typo, use the Solution Explorer window in VS.  Right-click the entry and click Rename.

Comment: I actually solved the problem but renaming the class name , did Edit->Refractor which changed the name of the file simultaneously as well