# Debugging a node.js project in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, debugging

I'm trying to expand a sudoku web application that I've checked out locally with visual studio 2022, namely this one: https://github.com/michel-kraemer/sudocle

My goal is to implement additional functionality and I'm using this as a learning experience in frontend development since I'm currently only doing backend. I can get the application to run in my localhost using node.js as detailed in the readme and I can modify some very basic things (e.g. changing texts) but to really get started, I would like to debug the application as it's running on my local server. The expectation is that I could set breakpoints in function that I want to modify to see the state of variables at runtime.

This is where I'm stuck. I've tried attaching the debugger to various processes and I can get it started from the next.config.js file, however I think it's not connected to my localhost then and I'm not sure how to trigger any functions from that point. Maybe I'm also misunderstanding the functions of a debugger in a web application.

For what it's worth, those are the sites I've been reading trying to solve my issue, so far with no luck:
https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/Debugging
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/troubleshooting-breakpoints?view=vs-2022
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_auto-attach
[F5 or Start Debugging Button is Greyed Out for Winform application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398767/f5-or-start-debugging-button-is-greyed-out-for-winform-application)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022

I hope a more experienced dev can help me out here.