# Binding redirect ignored

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

My website gives...

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

... and yet in web.config, I have...

```
<runtime xmlns="">
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

The version of System.Web.Http referenced by the project is 5.2.3.0.

I think I added this redirect before to fix this exact issue, but now it's not working. Any ideas?

Contents of packages.config...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AspNetMvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="JsonValue" version="0.6.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20715.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net4" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Unity" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Unity.Mvc4" version="1.6.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Unity.WebAPI" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Can you add your packages.config file to your question?

Comment: @DanSchnau Added.

Comment: I am not sure, but I guess MVC 4.0.0 and WebApi 5.2.3 are not compatible next to each other. I would try to downgrade WebApi or upgrade MVC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HRESULT: 0x80131040: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93879/hresult-0x80131040-the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-t)

Comment: It's likely that you have a dependency on an assembly that has a dependency on MVC 4.0.0, probably `Unity.Mvc4`.  Try removing that assembly and see if the error persists, or replace it with the `Unity.Mvc` package.

Comment: or you are missing some binding redirects `PM> Get-Project –All | Add-BindingRedirect`

Comment: @cloudikka I've never seen or needed that feature before.

Comment: @cloudikka MVC 4.0.0 and WebApi 5.2.3 are apparently running in production together.

Comment: @IanWarburton: I said am not sure about those versions. It was just a pointer.

Comment: @IanWarburton It is powershell command. you can check it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/ps-ref-add-bindingredirect)

Comment: @cloudikka Yes, I appreciate your help. I was merely clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many hours later I discovered that this error only appears on my default route and only on my dev machine. It was probably doing it all along and I assumed that something had changed after I re-checked out the code.

What is a word for this?