# Issues Previewing SSRS Reports in visual studio 2019

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to built new simple SSRS report in visual studio 2019 version. I am able to create solution and data sources and data sets everything fine. But when I am trying to preview the report to see how it looks in visual studio it gives below error.

[image: Error Screenshot]

But if I take same rdl file and deploy it on my report server and try to see the report it is able to fetch data just fine. But to enhance the report during development I do need preview frequently which seems to be not working. Could someone please help me with this.
I tried various solution suggested on google editing the xml content of rdl but no luck. I am suspecting it to be some kind of compatibility issue but sure what exactly is causing it.

My database is SQL 2016 SP2 version.

Comment: My SSRS is rusty, but are those assembly files in the error present in your project and resolved without any errors?

Comment: Out of interest, what is you target server version in the report project properties? I suspect you will need to remove remove the reporting services projects VS extension, do a repair on Visual Studio and then reinstall the extension.

Comment: Target server version is sql 2016 in project properties. Even I am suspecting the VS extension but not quite sure. I am afraid doing fresh installation of VS.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct dlls that are referenced in your report in the appropriate visual studio folder (eg: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSRS)

Comment: I can see Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll is present in required path.

Comment: Maybe reading this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93879/hresult-0x80131040-the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-t

Comment: I checked that but there are no external dependencies I am having. One thing I noticed there is update version of SSDT extension in available in VS 2019. Probably will try updating that and see if it works.

Comment: Try reinstalling VS report extension. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio

Comment: I updated the SSDT extension for visual studio and it worked.