# Unittests not running because of missing assembly

Tags: c#, nunit

I have created a unittest but when I try to run I receive the following error message in JetBrains Rider.
I have already tried a clean solution and a rebuild but to no avail.
The project in question does not reference the assembly mentioned.

```
Test not run

Last runner error: TestRunner: NUnitTestReporter Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=3.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

--- EXCEPTION #1/1 [LoggerException]
Message = “TestRunner: NUnitTestReporter Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=3.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)”
ExceptionPath = Root
ClassName = JetBrains.Util.LoggerException
HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600
StackTraceString = “
  at JetBrains.Util.ILoggerEx.LogMessage(ILogger this, LoggingLevel level, String message)
     at JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTestFramework.TestRunner.ServerEndpoint.<>c__DisplayClass9_2.<TryRegisterHandler>b__3()
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
     at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
”
```

Comment: This might be trivial, but did you try adding `NUnit NuGet package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to follow for this one:

1. Add nunit by using the package manager.
2. Verify that nunit is in the references of the unit testing project
3. Add the relevant [binding redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions)

This is an example, you might need to change it a bit.

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.framework"
    publicKeyToken="2638cd05610744eb"
    culture="en-us" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="3.12.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

You can find some more help [HRESULT: 0x80131040: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93879/hresult-0x80131040-the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-t)